# How to put background-image over the node borders in cytoscape js?

Tags: javascript, css, cytoscape.js, graph-visualization, cytoscape

So I am using cytoscape js and visualzing a graph. For every node, I have two background images. One is inside the node, and I want the other to be on the bottom-left of the node. Kind of like this:
[image]

Howevet the image in the bottom-left stays under the border of the node. But I want it to be over it. In the official site of Cytoscape js (https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/background-image) it says:

> To control the drawing order of background images (e.g overlay
> background images over borders), it is necessary to specify
> background-image-containment: over (default inside).

I thought this would solve my problem. Thus my code is like below:

```
            'background-image':  ['img1.png', 'img2.png'],
            'background-image-containment': ['inside', 'over'],
            'background-width': ['100%', '30%'],
            'background-height': ['100%', '30%'],
            'background-position-x': ['0px', '-10px'],
            'background-position-y':['0px', '-3px'],
            'background-clip': ['node', 'none']
```

I have tried it with another format too:

```
'background-image':  ['img1.png', 'img2.png'],
        'background-width': '100% 30%',
        'background-height': '100% 30%',
        'background-position-x': '0px -10px',
        'background-position-y':'0px 3px',
        'background-clip': 'node none',
        'background-image-containment': 'inside over',
        'bounds-expansion': '10 10',
```

But this doesn't work. The image is still under the node border. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Probably `'background-image-containment': 'inside over'` and `'background-image-containment': ['inside', 'over']` are not valid. If that's the case, you might see a warning message from the developer console. The message would be like `... is not a valid style`

Try `'background-image-containment': 'over'`